# Adjacent cells in a matrix (list of strings)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to calculate the number of adjacents cells from a certain position that meet a certain criteria in a wraparound matrix(a list with strings) - each cell has eight adjacent cells - .So far I've done this but it doesn't seem to successfully work (it doesn't pass the assert number 4):

```
def calculate_adjacents(matrix,row,column):

'''Calculates the number of cells adjacent to the cell in (row,column)''' 

        adjacents = 0
    for i in range(row-1,row+2):
        for j in range(column-1,column+2):
            if i == len(matrix) or j == len(matrix[i]):
                break
            if matrix[i][j] == "#":
                adjacents += 1
    return adjacents
```

Furthermore, it must verify this:

```
def test_calculate_adjacents():
    assert calculate_adjacents((['.']), 0, 0) == 0
    assert calculate_adjacents((['..', '..']), 0, 0) == 0
    assert calculate_adjacents((['..', '..']), 0, 1) == 0
    assert calculate_adjacents((['##', '..']), 0, 0) == 2
    assert calculate_adjacents((['##', '..']), 0, 1) == 2
    assert calculate_adjacents((['#.', '.#']), 0, 0) == 4
    assert calculate_adjacents((['##', '##']), 0, 0) == 8
    assert calculate_adjacents((['.#.', '#.#', '.#.']), 1, 1) == 4
    assert calculate_adjacents((['.#.', '..#', '.#.']), 1, 1) == 3
```

Comment: Seems like this is related to Conway's Game of Life. If "wrap-around" means what I think it means, then you need to be using modular arithmetic in expressions like `row - 1`, etc. It won't wrap around unless you code it. Also -- why `row + 2` rather than `row + 1`? Seems inconsistent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  *How* does this not work?  What values does it return for those tests, and where do you think it's having troubles?

Comment: Yes, it is related to Conway's Game of Life. I will try using modular arithmetic expressions. It doesn't pass the four assert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one small problem, common in Conway's "life" game: you're counting the central square as well.  Set the count to -1 if the central square is alive:

```
if matrix[row][column] == "#":
    adjacents = -1
else:
    adjacents = 0
```

Or, for the one-liner:

```
adjacents = -1 if matrix[row][column] == "#" else 0
```